# Go to particular div in rails 3

Tags: html

I have these two codes lines in subnativation.

```
 <%= link_to "Basic Info", request.request_uri + "#users_details"%>
 <%= link_to "Photos", request.request_uri + "#users_photos"%>
```

==>

```
/users/1#users_details
/users/1#users_photos
```

Its not navigating to that particular Div.

PS: users_details and users_photo are Id's of two different div's

Comment: do you have `<a name="users_details"></a>` somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#users_details` will navigate to `<a name='users_details'></a>` and `#users_photos` to `<a href='users_photos'></a>` somewhere in your HTML.

So put before your `users_details` div this: `<a name='users_details'></a>` and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your links in a style that makes it more obvious where you are actually trying to go: something like `<%= link_to "Basic Info", users_path(@user, :anchor => 'user_details') %>`. This will create a link to the `users#show` page but also include the anchor to go to any block level element with the id of `user_details`.